# line chart issue

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization, interactive, linechart

[image]

I have made the line chart given above. The problem is that I can't make that red line stop at the current hour. I want to be drawn only when the value is updated. I tried not defining the value, but it gives error in that case.

Here's [a link](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Overview)!

I have used the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://www.google.com/jsapi\"></script>
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
google.load(\"visualization\", \"1\", {packages:[\"corechart\"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Hour', 'Renewals Yesterday', 'Renewals Today']
      $ren_graph
      ]);

var options = {
      title: 'Renewals Cumulative Comparison Graph'
    };

var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id=\"chart_div\" style=\"width: 1200px; height: 300px;\"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try setting blank values as `null` and it should work.

Comment: I expanded with a reason to help future readers, feel free to mark it as the answer or improve on it to help folks in the future with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a "blank" value, you need to do two things.

First you need to set the value of the "blank" items to `null`

Second you need to have `interpolateNulls` in your options as false (this is the default behavior).

You can read more about `interpolateNulls` [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Configuration_Options):

> Whether to guess the value of missing points. If true, it will guess the value of any missing data based on neighboring points. If false, it will leave a break in the line at the unknown point.